# gettin this error in node jd error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance, binance-api-client

hi i am trying to implement a local orderbook using the binance api however i keep getting this error every now and then it does not always happen but if it does it will happen early on please help

this is the main file that runs calling an exports function from an external file to process the data coming from the web socket on message

```
wsClient.subscribeSpotDiffBookDepth("btcusdt");
wsClient.on('message', (data) => {

  // Setup and process order book information
  order_book.update_orderbook(data);
  if(order_book.ready === 1){
    order_book.get_orderbook_history();
  }

});

wsClient.on('error', err => {
  /* handle error */
    console.log("this is it 2 " + err);
});

wsClient.on('close', () => {
  /* ... */
});
```

exports function in external file

```
exports.update_orderbook = function(data) {
  if(data.e == "depthUpdate"){
    if(this.ready === 0){
      this.ready = 1;
      console.log("Stage 1 in play");
    }else{
      this.buffer += data;
    }

    if(this.ready === 2 && this.asks != null && this.bids != null){
      if(undefined !== this.asks && undefined !== this.bids && undefined !== data.a && undefined !== data.b){
        if(data.U <= this.lastUpdateId + 1 && data.u >= this.lastUpdateId + 1){

      // error is coming from calling this function-------------------------------------------------------
          var temp_array1 = sort_array(this.asks, data.a);
          var temp_array2 = sort_array(this.bids, data.b);
          this.asks = temp_array1;
          this.bids = temp_array2;
          this.lastUpdateId = data.u;

          console.log("Stage 3");
        }
      }
    }else{
      this.buffer += data;
    }
  }
}
```

function to sort and update the array

```
function sort_array(array1, array2){
  for(let x in array2){
    if(array2[x][1] == 0){
      for(let i in array2){
        if(array1[i][0] === array2[x][0]){
          array1.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }else{
      var in_array = false;
      for(let i in array1){
        // this seems to be the problem area---------------------------------------------------------
        if(array1[i][0] === array2[x][0]){ 
          array1[i] = array2[x];
          in_array = true;
        }
      }
      if(!in_array){
        array1.push(array2[x]);
      }
    }
  }
  return array1;
}
```

error log

[image]

Comment: The error log clearly states the issue is in orderBook.js 78:21. Can you show what that line is?

Comment: there is a comment above the line with the error in exports.update_orderbook